# Tor stopped working upon installing new router/modem

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, network-configuration, routers

Here is the log regarding the problem:

```
6/6/2016 17:16:47 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or
  accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
6/6/2016 17:16:47 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
6/6/2016 17:16:47 PM.200 [WARN] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9150: 
  Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]
```

Port forwarding doesn't resolves the problem and neither does running as admin, disabling windows firewall, changing router firewalls ettings nor using bridges works.

Answer (score 2):

`[WARN] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9150: Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]`

This is something local, not related to censorship or a new router *(unless the router appears as an "unknown network" and has triggered different firewall rules or profiles)*. Something is stopping you binding to port. This is either some access control mechanism (firewall, packetfilter, antivirus, etc) *or* something is already bound to that port number.

I think the equivalent `netstat` command on windows would be something like `netstat -p tcp` in cmd.exe to see if that port is in use.

> WSAEACCES
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions.
>
> Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind
>   function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another
>   application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same
>   address with exclusive access.

Source: [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wsaeacces)